# Logging in Apache Camel Routers, changing values of MDC fields

Tags: logging, apache-camel, elastic-stack

I am quite new to Apache camel, and I am trying to get my routes to log to specific data points. As  I understand from the interface UnitOfWork it looks to only allow a hook before the route starts and after. I'm  looking for an option where I can dynamically update a field during a route. The logs are going off to an ELK stack to allow dashboard creation.

For example, like this where my checkpoint field is updated, or the elapsed time field is only included in a specific entry.

```
{"@timestamp":"2021-05-18T15:32:15.679-04:00","message”:”Test”,”logger_name":"MySpringBootRouter", ”checkpoint”:”ROUTE_START"}
{"@timestamp":"2021-05-18T15:32:15.679-04:00","message”:”Test”,”logger_name":"MySpringBootRouter", ”checkpoint”:”TRANSFORM_COMPLETE”}
{"@timestamp":"2021-05-18T15:32:15.679-04:00","message”:”Test”,”logger_name":"MySpringBootRouter", ”checkpoint”:”ROUTE_COMPLETE”, “elapsedTime”:”12345”}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are actually asking for. MDC is Camel independent. You can always define properties via `MDC.put(var, value)`. Note however that the value is thread-local only, so if you have multiple threads active you'd need to copy these values over. If you're asking for a way to set those values in the MDC context i.e. from Camel's message header, automatically, you might have a look at a [custom MDC unit of work implementation](https://github.com/RovoMe/camel-rest-dsl-with-spring-security/blob/master/src/main/java/at/rovo/awsxray/config/mdc/CustomMDCUnitOfWork.java) ...

Comment: ... [its factory implementation](https://github.com/RovoMe/camel-rest-dsl-with-spring-security/blob/master/src/main/java/at/rovo/awsxray/config/mdc/CustomUnitOfWorkFactory.java) as well as how these classes are [used](https://github.com/RovoMe/camel-rest-dsl-with-spring-security/blob/master/src/main/java/at/rovo/awsxray/config/SpringConfig.java#L89-L91)